# How to remove all special characters and extra spaces between words with Regex in PostgreSQL

Tags: regex, postgresql

In migrating a text string from one database to another, I need to eliminate all special characters and keep only one space between words.

Unfortunately, the below code eliminates all spaces between words -- not what I want.

Here is the code I have. The "sig" field is wrong (it removes all spaces without leaving one space). Where did I go wrong?
TIA

```
WITH dbl_medications AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM dblink('select medname, sig, form from medications')
    AS t1(medname text, sig text, form text)
    ORDER BY medname, form, sig
    )
INSERT INTO medications (medname, sig, form)    
    SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(LOWER(REGEXP_REPLACE(medname,'[^a-zA-Z0-9 /-]','','g')), '^ +| +$| +(?= )', '', 'g'),
           REGEXP_REPLACE(LOWER(REGEXP_REPLACE(sig,'[^0-9a-zA-Z:/]',' ','g')), '^ +| +$| +(?= )', '', 'g'),
           LOWER(REGEXP_REPLACE(form,'[^a-zA-Z]','','g'))         
    FROM dbl_medications
    ORDER BY 1,3,2
ON CONFLICT (medname, sig, form) DO NOTHING;
```

Comment: Are you sure the characters are spaces and not some other non-printable character such as a tab?

Comment: @Bohemian Yes. Currently all spaces are being removed betweenTheWords. :)

Comment: The order of operations is fine, and it should work. Try replacing spaces with `[[:space:]]`: `'^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$|[[:space:]]+(?=[[:space:]])'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I was unaware of using `[[:space:]]` notation. Thanks. Further study reviled the primary error was not including a space in the inner most allowed character list. It should be: `REGEXP_REPLACE(LOWER(REGEXP_REPLACE(sig,'[^0-9a-zA-Z ;:/]','','g')), '^ +| +$| +(?= )', '', 'g')`. There is a space between the Z and the ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sql
REGEXP_REPLACE(LOWER(REGEXP_REPLACE(sig,'[^[:alnum:][:space:]:/]+',' ','g')), '^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$|[[:space:]]+(?=[[:space:]])', '', 'g')
```

The first `[^[:alnum:][:space:]:/]+` regex is used to replace chunks of one or more chars other than alphanumeric, whitespace, `:` and `/` chars with a single space.

The `^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$|[[:space:]]+(?=[[:space:]])` regex is used to remove leading (`^[[:space:]]+`) and trailing (`[[:space:]]+$`) whitespaces, and remove excessive whitespace (`[[:space:]]+(?=[[:space:]])`).